# bash prepend text to every line printed by commands

Tags: bash, stdout

I'm trying to find a way to do something like this:

```
# script.sh:
cmd0
set_prepend "some text"
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
unset_prepend
cmd4
```

Then whatever stdout generated by cmd1, 2 and 3, every line will be prepended by "some text". There is no relationship between the commands, and the commands can be anything (ls, cat, awk, whatever):

```
$ script.sh
cmd0 line1
...
cmd0 lineN0
some text cmd1 line1
some text ...
some text cmd1 lineN1
some text cmd2 line1
some text ...
some text cmd2 lineN2
some text cmd3 line1
some text ...
some text cmd3 lineN3
cmd4 line1
...
cmd4 lineN4
```

The only way I can think of is far from elegant:

```
script.sh | prepender
```

and for each line received by prepender, it checks the existence of a file; if the file exists, the contents are the text to prepend; and set_prepend would create that file and unset_prepend would remove it. However buffering would interfere with this, so it would have to be turned off, and I'm not sure how to garantee that a line going to stdout will be processed by prepender before the next script cmd is execute (otherwise race condition possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exec` to redirect output to a pipe. You'll need to save the old `stdout` in another FD so you can restore it later.

```
set_prepend() {
    exec 3>&1 | sed "s/^/$1 /"
}
unset_prepend() {
    exec >&3 3>&-
}
```

Comment: ok i used exec once before :> and the docs are clear, if exec without a command then the current shell output is redirected per the exec... but then I'm confused: E.g. in the unset, it seems you are redirecting 1 to 3, then closing 3, but that can't be right; and in the set, you redirect a new FD, 3, to stdout 1, but nothing ever gets sent to FD 3... there's something I am not understanding about redirection, if you could expand that would be much appreciated

Comment: OK I tihnk I got it: the 3>&1 means everything sent to FD 3 will go to stdout, not to FD 1; and the pipe means stdout will go to the pipe. Then to restore, you make 1 go to 3, but 3 is going to stdout, so really 1 is back to stdout, and then close FD 3. It's sheer insanity and brilliant at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you got it. The left-to-right order matters -- you redirect 1 to 3, then close 3, but 1 is still open.